# Do there exist families of groups $G_{s}$ such that $\forall s\in[0,1], |G_{s}|=\mathfrak{c}$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Do there exist families of isomorphism classes of groups $G_{s}$ such that $\forall s\in[0,1], |G_{s}|=\mathfrak{c}$, where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the cardinality of the continuum, and for any $a,b\in[0,1], a\neq b$, $G_{a}$≇$G_{b}$?

Comment: Given your tags: presumably you are asking for these to be Lie groups? and if so, by (non)isomorphism, do you mean in the sense of bicontinuous group isomorphism?

Comment: I don't think I actually require that they be Lie groups -- that would be a nice bonus, though, and yes, if they were Lie groups, then I do mean in the sense of a bicontinuous group isomorphism.

Comment: Well, if you didn't need them to be Lie groups, my guess would be that one could cook up discrete examples, although I don't claim to see exactly how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking if there are families $\{G_t:t\in[0,1]\}$ of Lie groups of positive dimension whose elements are non-isomorphic in pairs.

There are examples of curves of non-isomorphic Lie groups in the class of nilpotent groups. In fact, as soon as the dimension is greater or equal to $7$, there are continuously-many non-isomorphic *filiform* Lie algebras, so the same thing happens for groups (filiform Lie algebras are "maximally non-abelian" nilpotent Lie algebras) This is discussed in detail, for example, in the book by Goze on *Nilpotent Lie algebras*.

As the dimension grows, we find families of unbounded dimension.
In general, the nilpotent part of the world is filled with many, many examples.

Comment: (Notice that a bicontinuous isomorphism between Lie groups is in fact a bidifferentiable, so looking at Lie algebras is enough to tell groups apart)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the question was about bicontinuous isomorphism classes of Lie groups, and that question was answered by Mariano Suarez-Alvarez.
Now, I suspect that many of these Lie-groups are in fact isomorphic algebraically, just not by a bicontinuous isomorphism.

Let me answer the question literally:  There is a family of continuum many, pairwise non-isomorphic groups of size continuum.  Actually, there is such a family of countable groups.

Namely, let $\mathbb P$ denote the set of prime numbers.
For each infinite set $S\subseteq\mathbb P$ let $G_S$ be the direct sum of the abelian groups $\mathbb Z_p$, $p\in S$.  The groups $G_S$ are pairwise non-isomorphic since if $S,T\subseteq\mathbb P$ and $p\in S\setminus T$, then $G_T$ has no element of order $p$ but $G_S$ does.

Now, the groups $G_S$ are countable.  If you want size continuum, you can either take the cartesian product instead of direct sum, or simply multiply everything with $\mathbb R$.  In either case you get a family of pairwise nonisomorphic groups of size $2^{\aleph_0}$.